# auth .inMemoryAuthentication In spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my application, there are more than 100 users. How can put their username password and roles in the below code?

I have tried so many logic but could not succeed.

```java
auth
.inMemoryAuthentication()
.withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER").and()
  .withUser("operator").password("password").roles("OPERATOR").and()
  .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN").and();
```

Comment: You don't. inMemoryAuthentication is just for "playing". In the real world, you'll store that information in a database and you wouldn't use inMemoryAuthentication.

Comment: But if i do not put my user,password and role then my application is not working because i am using themeleaf concept in application                                                  
 <a data-th-if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''USER'')')}" href="/requestlogviews" data-th-href="@{/requestlogviews}" role="button" aria-haspopup="false" aria-expanded="false" data-th-text="#{label_home}">Home</a>            In application user can perform operation and view the process based on role based i am new please suggest me

Comment: Consider using JDBC Authentication. You can store your users in a database and Spring Security (and Thymeleaf) will still be able to retrieve the roles. Check out the JDBC Authentication section in the [Spring Security reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-jdbc).